# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in Android

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am developing an Android client for Microsoft Dynamics NAV. I am using ksoap2 for making communication with NAV webservices. I used MarshalDate class to serialize date. When I pass Date to webservice I am getting an error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

> MarshalDate.java

```
public class MarshalDate implements Marshal { 

public static Class DATE_CLASS = new Date().getClass();
public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException { 
    return IsoDate.stringToDate(parser.nextText(), IsoDate.DATE_TIME); 
    } 
public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) { 
    cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "dateTime", Date.class, this); }
public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
    writer.text(IsoDate.dateToString((Date) obj, IsoDate.DATE_TIME)); } }
```

My object for salesordercard,

> SalesOrderCard.java

```
    public class SalesOrderCard implements KvmSerializable
{
    String Key;
    String No;
    String Sell_to_Customer_No;
    Sales_Order_Line_List Salesorderlinelist;
        String ShopNo;
        Date OrderDate;
    double Received_Amount;
    boolean Cheque;


    public SalesOrderCard(){}


    public SalesOrderCard(String key,String no,String selltocustno,Sales_Order_Line_List salesorderline,String shopno,Date orderdate ,double received_Amount,boolean  cheque) {

        Key = key;
        No = no;
        Sell_to_Customer_No = selltocustno;
        Salesorderlinelist=salesorderline;
        ShopNo=shopno;
        OrderDate=orderdate;
        received_Amount=Received_Amount;
        Cheque=cheque;

    }


    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

        switch(arg0)
        {
        case 0:
            return Key;


        case 1:
            return No;


        case 2:
            return Sell_to_Customer_No;

        case 3:
            return Salesorderlinelist;

        case 4:
            return ShopNo;

        case 5:
            return Received_Amount;


        case 6:
            return Cheque;

        case 7:
            return OrderDate;


        }

        return null;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 8;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Key";
            break;

        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "No";
            break;

        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Sell_to_Customer_No";
            break;

        case 3:
            info.type = Sales_Order_Line_List.class;
            info.name = "SalesLines";
            break;

        case 4:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Shop_No";
            break;

       case 5:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "Received_Amount";
            break;

       case 6:
           info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
           info.name = "Cheque";
           break;

      case 7:
          info.type = MarshalDate2.DATE_CLASS;
         info.name = "Order_Date";
           break;





        default:break;
        }
    }

    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {

        switch(index)
        {

        case 0:
            Key = value.toString();
            break;

        case 1:
            No = value.toString();
            break;

        case 2:
            Sell_to_Customer_No = value.toString();
            break;

        case 3:
            Salesorderlinelist = (Sales_Order_Line_List)value;
            break;

        case 4:
            ShopNo = value.toString();
            break;

        case 5:
            Received_Amount =  Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
            break;

        case 6:
            Cheque =  Boolean.parseBoolean(value.toString());
            break;

        case 7:

            OrderDate=(Date)value;
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I am passing date like,

```
    String DateString="22-05-2014 19:32:52";
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    d=(Date)format.parse(DateString);

    SalesOrderCard cr=new SalesOrderCard();
    cr.OrderDate=d;


    PropertyInfo custProp = new PropertyInfo();
   custProp.setName("SalesOrderCard");
   custProp.setValue(cr);
   custProp.setType(SalesOrderCard.class);
   request.addProperty(custProp);
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
   md.register(envelope);
   MarshalDate mdate=new MarshalDate();
   mdate.register(envelope);
```

Comment: just a question, did you try the format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes I have tried that format. Same error

Comment: Did you try passing the date in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`?

Comment: So have you looked at the request going over the wire? What does it look like?

Comment: Are you sure this dateformat is supported? Just tried to look in their docs and I found `yyyy-MM-DD HH.mm.ss`. But I don't know if I ended up in the right docs? -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301059.aspx  (Chapter DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming d is a Date this code looks correct

```
String DateString="22-05-2014 19:32:52";
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
d=(Date)format.parse(DateString);
```

I suspect this line may be the problem

```
writer.text(IsoDate.dateToString((Date) obj, IsoDate.DATE_TIME));
```

If you know the format writer.text expects then I would try using SimpleDateFormat to create the string for you instead:

```
String dateString = format.format((Date)obj);
```